# How to scroll to last row of a Sqlite model in a QTableView?

Tags: sqlite, pyqt, qtableview

I have a Sqlite model of several 1000 rows attached to a QTableView. I can view the rows in the QTableView but when I scroll to the bottom of the QTableView, I can only get to the end of the first few 100 rows. If I keep pulling on the scrollbar button, new rows get appended to the view but I cannot easily scroll to the end. Once all rows are appended to the view, I can then easily scroll from top to bottom without problem.

Here's the important part of the code (which is just standard):

```
self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
self.db.setDatabaseName(dbFileName)

self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self.db)
self.model.setTable("results")
self.model.select()
self.tableViewResults.setModel(self.model)
```

I must be missing something very simple. Any suggestions?

Laurence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QSqlTableModel` loads data lazily, i.e. it will load the items when it's asked for. And `QTableView` will ask for items if it needs to *display* them. That delay you observe is the part that `QSqlTableModel` fetches new data from the database.

There is also [an issue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html#details), if SQL drivers doesn't report Query size, and SQLite is one of them:

> If the database doesn't return the number of selected rows in a query,
>   the model will fetch rows incrementally. See fetchMore() for more
>   information.

So the model actually doesn't know how many items there will be *until* it loads all the items.

In order to eliminate the delay you should load all data beforehand (as [`fetchMore`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html#fetchMore) suggests):

```
self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
self.db.setDatabaseName(dbFileName)

self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self.db)
self.model.setTable("results")
self.model.select()
while self.model.canFetchMore():
    self.model.fetchMore()
self.tableViewResults.setModel(self.model)
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed to do.